# Receive SMS after closing App in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I need to read incoming SMS. I'm using `BroadcastReceiver` for this. It's working fine but when app is closed `BroadcastReceiver` also close. 
Here is code that I'm using.
**Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<!--other code -->
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**IncomingSms**

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
}
```

The code is working fine but want it to run even App is closed. I want to read SMS whenever it come. means this broadcast run lifetime never close until App uninstall. I think I need service for this but how can I do that, I'm new in android.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to write **IntentService** for that, you can start such service in broadcast receiver, because broadcast reciever can not execute for long time.

Comment: Can you please write a little code, How can I do that, sorry for asking but I'm new in it. thanks