# Run App in Background in Android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I want to run app in background even app is closed. I need to read the sms when anyone receive. For this I'm using `IntentService` and `BroadcastReceiver` But I don't know why the code is not working. Here is my code.

**Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
 <!-- Other code -->
 <service android:name=".ServiceCommunicator"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
      // Inside onCreate method
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceCommunicator.class);
     startService(intent);
```

**ServiceCommunicator**

```
 public class ServiceCommunicator extends IntentService
{
private SMSreceiver mSMSreceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

public ServiceCommunicator(){
    super("ServiceCommunicator");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mSMSreceiver = new SMSreceiver();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
}


private class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String strMessage = "";

        if ( extras != null )
        {
            Object[] smsextras = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsextras.length; i++ )
            {
                SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsextras[i]);

                String strMsgBody = smsmsg.getMessageBody().toString();
                String strMsgSrc = smsmsg.getOriginatingAddress();

                strMessage += "SMS from " + strMsgSrc + " : " + strMsgBody;

                Log.i(TAG, strMessage);
                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: "+ strMsgSrc + ", message: " + strMsgBody, duration);
                toast.show();
            }

        }

    }

}
 }
```

What's the problem with this code. I want to run this code even user close App.

Comment: you have to register brodcast first, in onmessage receive method start intent service

Comment: `IntentService`s stop themselves after `onHandleIntent()` finishes. Use a regular `Service` instead. You really shouldn't need to do this, though. If you're not getting that broadcast in a manifest-registered Receiver, then there's likely something else going on that you should remedy first. For example: make sure you've run your app at least once after installation, before receiving a message, to bring it out of the _stopped_ state; check your device for any additional settings/permissions that might be restricting third-party apps from getting SMS in the background; etc.

Comment: @MikeM. I register the broadcast receiver in mainfest file, And create a public class `SMSreceiver` which extends from `Broadcastreceiver` when I run my app its working fine but when I close app it also stop reading sms. Here is [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993912/receive-sms-after-closing-app-in-android/) that I posted before but someone said that I need `IntentService` for this. I'm new in android could you please take a look at this question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that question, which is why I mentioned the manifest-registered Receiver. As I mentioned, make sure to run your app once after installation, and check your device for non-standard permissions or settings that may be interfering. Also, if you're closing your app by force-stopping it, then that Receiver in the manifest won't work again until you next run your app. That's by design, since Android version 3.1.

Comment: App is working fine even it's in  a resume state. But after closing it's not work. I didn't understand what do you mean by force-stopping. I just close the app usual. I'm using `Huawei y5ii` phone I don't think there is any additional permission is required.

Comment: Many other apps working fine in Background like Facebook, Instagram and whatsapp etc. How these are working.

Comment: @MikeM. Simply your mean to run App in Background there is no service required just register the Broadcast in manifest and it start working. Right ?

Comment: Your app doesn't need to be constantly running in the background to get the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast, at least on stock Android. That's why I suggested that, if yours stops getting that broadcast while it's not in the foreground, you should check your device for extra settings/permissions beyond the standard Android ones. If your device is a Huawei, then I wouldn't be surprised if it does have something blocking. I can't confirm that, though, which is why I don't answer these questions anymore. They just turn into hours-long comment threads. I really can't help if your device isn't standard.

Answer (score -2):

I think, you'll have to use "Service". It helps to keep running the app in background.
This might help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYctmRwYHOg